# Could any one share where the ipv6 address stores in registry. I am using windows7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, ipv6

Could any one share where the ipv6 address stores in registry. I am using windows7.
I am looking in the path...
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\Interfaces{22025eb7-322d-47e4-9c6e-86fad5b06fb8}

for ipv6 address.. Is this right place? 
If this is right place i am not able to find the ip address which i set thru the Local area connection->Properties->Internet Protocol Version 6(Tcp/ip6)-> Properties -> Seleted the "Use the following IPv6 address" option button.

Then entered, ipv6, subnet prefixlen , gateway, dns1, dns2.
But where it is saved in registry, i was not able to find.
Please help me on this.
Can any one give me hint that the key of registry?

Thanks,
Haranadh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the current IP addresses (there can be multiple), from and command prompt (`cmd` or PowerShell) execute: `ipconfig` (or, for more details `ipconfig /all`).

You can also use `netsh` or WMI (class `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`) to get this information.

> ipv6 address stores in registry

Often this will be determined dynamically via DHCP, so is non-persistent. So may not always be held in the registry.

Comment: Hi Richard, Really many thanks for replying my question very quickly. I tried using the wmi class which you specified earlier. But the "enablestatic" method is failing while i am setting the ipv6 address. Is there any way we can set the ipv6 address using Wmi class (Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration). I am a developer, struggling a lot to fix this. I am using netsh hardcode command for fix this. If you can refer me a sample code will help me a huge. I should thanks you a ton. :)
I am mainly looking for ipv6 address,sub net prefix length,gateway, dns1, alternatedns2 (for ipv6).
yours hara

Comment: If `netsh` works, then just use that. (And I don't know of any samples using `EnableStatic` method of `NetworkAdapterConfiguratio`. If you want the WMI route, then start by checking the return value against the MSDN docs.